# finding the max index in a moving window

Tags: matlab

I want to find the max element's index for a moving window. I tried to do it as the following (a simple example):

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

[m,I]=max(x(1:5))

ans
m=5

I=5
```

then if I say

```
[m2,I2]=max(x(3:7));
```

I get

```
ans

m2=7
I2=5
```

I want a way to give me the index with reference to the original big vector not the subvector which was passed to the function (I want I2 to give me 7 not 5).
Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
x = [2,5,6,8,4,5,10,33];
start_w = 4;
end_w = 7;

[m,I] = max(x(start_w:end_w));

I = I + start_w - 1; %reindex to x, so that x(I)==m
```

Comment: I put thins into a loop and it worked! thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use sliding window operation to get the local max indexes and add the global window xenter indexes afterwards:

```
function idx = maxidx(x)
[~,idx] = max(x);
```

and:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3]; % test array
W = 5; % window width
% moving max idx function -> local indexes
B = colfilt(x,[1 W],'sliding',@maxidx);
% index addition to convert local indexes to global
addedIdx = (1:length(x)) - floor((W+1)/2); 
% add local indexes with global addition
res = B + addedIdx

res = 
    3     4     5     6     7     8     9     9     9     9     9
```

Comment: thank you very much for  your help, I did it by adding the window length to each address.